# My progressbar does not sync with my count down timer

Tags: java, android, android-studio, wear-os

Here I have made this method for starting my timer and the one below it updates the timer:

```
 private void startTimer()
{
    mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(mTimeLeftInMillis, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            mTimeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished;
            updateCountDownText();
            progress++;
            pb.setProgress((int)progress*100/((int)millisUntilFinished/1000));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish()
        {
            progress++;
            pb.setProgress(100);
            //Vibration
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26)
            {
                ((Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE)).vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(150, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity2.this,"Done",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                ((Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE)).vibrate(VibrationEffect.createWaveform(new long[]{150}, new int[]{VibrationEffect.EFFECT_CLICK},-1));
            }
        }
    }.start();
}


 private void updateCountDownText()
{

    //time in minutes and seconds
    int minutes = (int)(mTimeLeftInMillis/1000)/60;
    int seconds = (int)(mTimeLeftInMillis/1000)%60;
    //formating the above to appear as String
    String timeLeftFormatted = String.format("%02d:%02d",minutes,seconds);
    timer.setText(timeLeftFormatted);
}
```

"pb" is the name of my progressbar. It keeps finishing earlier than the countdown by 2 minutes and I don't know how to synchronize them. Also upon completion the vibration is not triggered for some reason even though it did before. "progress" is initialized as zero as a global variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
long millisInFuture;

private void startTimer() {
    millisInFuture = mTimeLeftInMillis;
    mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(mTimeLeftInMillis, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            mTimeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished;
            updateCountDownText();
            long millisPassed = millisInFuture - mTimeLeftInMillis;
            progress = (int) (millisPassed * 100 / millisInFuture);
            pb.setProgress(progress);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            pb.setProgress(100);
            Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                VibrationEffect effect =
                        VibrationEffect.createOneShot(150, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE);
                vibrator.vibrate(effect);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity2.this, "Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                vibrator.vibrate(150);
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Comment: I don't know if it works or not because the timer stopped counting the progress bar is working though

Comment: @MohamedElKayal If you don't know then try to run this code and let me know the result.

Comment: I did run it I meant that after I did the counter did not update only the progress bar. I'll try running it again to see if I missed anything.

Comment: "the counter" you mentioned in your comment is the `timer` TextView in your code, isn't it?

Comment: I think it's working just waiting for it to finish, thanks in advance and yes the counter is the timer TextView.

Comment: Good to hear that. By the way, if my answer is useful for you, then you can mark or vote it as a useful answer. This will help me improving my answers in the future.

Comment: Update: it is working perfectly. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

But I don't see when you initialize your progressbar.
If you set pb.max ( or setMax in Java ) = 100
And on each onTick call a method :

```
private changePb(long millisUntilFinished){
    pb.progress = (millisUntilFinished / millisStartValue) * 100
}
```

Where millisStartValue was the first value you put in new CountDownTimer(mTimeLeftInMillis

And in onFinish, you don't have to put new value for progressbar.

Comment: do I initialize the progressbar as zero? Is that what you mean?

Comment: yes, just checking if progress bar is set to max value = 100 ( may be in your layout)

Comment: max is set to 100 and progress set to zero so what am I missing here?